# Mock if __name__ == "__main__":

Tags: python, mocking

I need to write test cases for my project, however I am stuck at one line of code. How can I mock this line `if __name__ == "__main__"`? Please provide ways to do this. Any help/advice will be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! (Am I qualified to say that?) Please provide a further explanation / example.

Comment: you dont want to create tests for that line

Answer (score 2):

Don't. You don't need to.

Instead of writing

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # complicated stuff to test...
```

write

```
def main():
    # complicated stuff to test...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then you can just test `main` like any other function, without having to mess with `__name__` or try to somehow get the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block to run twice when you want to run two tests on it.